# Problem creating sequence diagram in papyrus

Tags: eclipse, uml, sequence-diagram, papyrus

I created simple sequence diagram in Papyrus.

It has lifeline1, lifeline2, and one async message from lifeline1 to lifeline2. When i delete message from diagram (it stays in model), and try to drag and drop that message from model to diagram it gives an error: “Element can not be dropped. For unknown reason, this link can not be dropped between sekvenca::Interaction1::Lifeline1 and sekvenca::Interaction1::Lifeline2.”

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

I just reproduced your issue with the last Papyrus build. It seems to be a bug as it should be permitted to drop an existing Message. You can report the bug in the bug tracker

[Link to Papyrus Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/describecomponents.cgi?product=Papyrus)

and/or post direclty on the Papyrus forum. It is much more active

[Link to the Papyrus forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=121)